# Deprecated List in Bootstrap 3.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, deprecated

I recently updated from Bootstrap 3.0 to 3.2, in the docs I've seen that e.g. `@screen-sm` is now deprecated.

Is there a general deprecated list where I can see what has been deprecated from 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Deprecations are mentioned in the changelogs:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases

better than nothing, I guess.

Comment: Deprecations are also mentioned in comments in the Less files directly adjacent to where each variable is defined.